# Xcode - Install .deb within the app

Tags: ios, xcode, deb, cydia

I am developing an application similar to Cydia. Users will be able to browse packages and install them. The thing is, I need a way for .deb files to be installed without leaving the app, if the user taps the install button. I have tried looking at similar questions on stack overflow and the internet but none of them work. I am running Xcode 5 and the app is intended to run on jail-broken devices. I am relatively new to Xcode so please try to explain in a way I will understand. Thanks :)

Comment: Not this again. Another newbie programmer wants to develop an app for a jailbroken device. I'm not gonna explain you how to write whole app. I can only nudge you in the right direction. You need to grant your app root permissions and then execute `dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE`, simple as that and just like Cydia does it. Also, Cydia is open source, you can find your answer there too.

Comment: But how do I grant it root permissions??